# Which type of install file I should use, i386 or amd64?

Tags: intel

I have a dell inspiron 13 laptop currently running windows. I would like to install Ubuntu server (not desktop) the file I download is "ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.iso" but when I try to download wireless package they have both amd64 and i386.

Why isn't there an i386 install file for Intel based computers? Why do packages have both versions?

Which installer should I use for my Intel based PC? and which packages should I use?

Comment: What __wireless package__ are you referring to???? If you have the _iso_ then go ahead and install!

Comment: I think you're confused about the two. `i386` are for 32-bit operating systems, and `amd64` is for 64-bit.   You should use the one based on what system you have.  So if you have a 64-bit system, install the 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 5):

The term *amd64* originated when only AMD produced a 64-bit capable CPU. That has not been the case for many years, as you know. If your Dell supports 64-bit in Windows, and we're fairly confident that it does, the the amd64 iso is what you want.

Today, *amd64* simply means 64-bit and *i386*, in this context, means 32-bit.

Comment: more like intel's 64bit cpu of the time (Itanium aka `ia64`) wasn't x86-compatible (and was prohibitively expensive), so amd's `x86_64` (aka `amd64`) alternative was preferred.

Comment: Thanks, it make sense, I will always pick amd64 from now on