# How to install Mattermost desktop application

Tags: command-line, software-installation

When I tried to install Mattermost desktop app in Ubuntu,
I've downloaded and extracted [.tar.gz file](https://releases.mattermost.com/desktop/4.1.2/mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-x64.tar.gz).

I didn't find any file named `configure` inside that.

How to install the app?

Comment: A config file contains configuration. It's not supposed to be executed. What exactly did you do so far? What did you download and where from? What commands have you run?

Comment: i've downloaded a tar.gz file and extracted it.  i didn't find any file named configure to do ./configure . there is a directory named configue. .json file located inside that.   i'm not getting how to install that app.

Comment: i couldn't find .deb file for this version

Comment: when i tried to install .deb files, "dependency problems - leaving unconfigured"
occured

Answer (score 1):

> Unofficial, community-driven .deb packages are available for Ubuntu
>   and Debian-based systems.
>
> 1. Download the latest version of the Mattermost desktop app:
>
>    ```
>    mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-amd64.deb # 64-bit systems
>    ```
>
>    or
>
>    ```
>    mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-i386.deb # 32-bit systems
>    ```
> 2. At the command line, execute one of the following commands depending on the package that you downloaded:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install -y ./mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-amd64.deb # 64-bit systems
>    ```
>
>    or
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install -y ./mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-i386.deb # 32-bit systems
>    ```
>
>    The following NEW packages will be installed: mattermost-desktop
> 3. To run Mattermost, open the Dash and type *mattermost*, then click the Mattermost icon.

<sub>**Source:** [Desktop Appllication Install Guides – Mattermost 5.1 documentation](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/desktop.html#ubuntu-and-debian-based-systems)</sub>

Comment: when i tried to install .deb files, "dependency problems - leaving unconfigured" occured

Comment: try this `apt-get install filename.deb `    this command will install your dependency automaticly

Comment: @venkatsai Edited my answer with updated commands in Step 2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `.deb` installer for Mattermost desktop application, although the website authors seem to prefer `tar.gz` for an unclear reason. Instead of downloading the `tar.gz` file, proceed to the [Ubuntu and Debian-based systems](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/desktop.html#ubuntu-and-debian-based-systems) section of the [Install guide](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/desktop.html).

From this page, download the file [appropriate for your architecture](https://askubuntu.com/q/897221/250300) and run it, e.g.:

```
sudo dpkg -i mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-amd64.deb
```

You can also [use APT to solve potential dependency problems automatically](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/250300).
In the folder with the downloaded file, run:

```
sudo apt install ./mattermost-desktop-4.1.2-linux-amd64.deb
```